# zeros of polynomials

Tags: calculus, number-theory, polynomials

Let $1>\epsilon>0$ and $0<m<n<k$ be real numbers, and let
$$
f=x^m-x^{m\epsilon}, \ g=x^n-x^{n\epsilon}, \ h=x^k-x^{k\epsilon}
$$
Does there exists $0<x<1$ such that $f(x)-g(x)=f(x)-h(x)=0$ ($f=g=h$)? Numerically it seems that it cannot happen.

Remark: $f-g,f-h$ has a unique zero in $(0,1)$ (Roll's theorem)

I  encountered this  question during my research, and I am not sure what is the right way to attack it. Even proving something  in the case when $n,m,k$  are natural  numbers is not trivial.
In fact, even saying something for natural numbers will be a nice step.

I can show several results in some case:

Case 1: $m=1$ and $n,k$ are natural numbers.

Define $x^{\epsilon}=y$. Then,
$$
x-y=x^n-y^n=x^k-y^k
$$
Dividing by $x-y$ we can see that
$$
1=(x^{n-1}+..+y^{n-1})=(x^{k-1}+..+y^{k-1})
$$
Therefore
$$
1=(x^{n-1}+..+y^{n-1})^{k-1}=(x^{k-1}+..+y^{k-1})^{n-1}
$$
Now using the multinomia formula one can verify that each monomial of the form $x^l y^{(n-1)(k-1)-l}$ in
$(x^{n-1}+..+y^{n-1})^{k-1}$ occurs more (or) equal times than in $(x^{k-1}+..+y^{k-1})^{n-1}$
and the inequality is strict for some monomials. Therefore,
$$
(x^{n-1}+..+y^{n-1})^{k-1}>(x^{k-1}+..+y^{k-1})^{n-1}
$$
and we get a contradiction.

thanks.

Comment: I am confused by your posting.  Isn't it the case that $\{f - g = f - h\} \iff \{g=h\},~$ for some particular value of $x$?  Assuming so, why is the function $f$ introduced at all?

Comment: you are right, I forgot to  write =0. I corrected it. I meant f=g=h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function $\phi(x) = x - x^\epsilon$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Show that $\phi$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, c]$ and strictly increasing on $[c, 1]$ for some $c \in (0, 1)$, depending on $\epsilon$.

It follows that for any $y \in \Bbb R$ there are *at most two* arguments $x\in [0, 1] \in $ with $\phi(x) = y$.

If $0 < m < n < k$ and $x \in (0, 1)$ then $0 < x^k < x^n < x^m < 1$, therefore it is not possible that
$$
 \phi(x^m) = \phi(x^n) = \phi(x^k)
$$
and that is your assertion.

Comment: thanks, very simple and elegant